# Is there any good way to get a indication if a computer can run a specific program/software?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, v8, measurement

Is there any good way too get a indication if a computer is capable to run a program/software without any performance problem, using pure JavaScript (Google V8), C++ (Windows, Mac OS & Linux), by requiring as little information as possible from the software creator (like CPU score, GPU score)?

That way can I give my users a good indication whether their computer is good enough to run the software or not, so the user doesn't need to download and install it from the first place if she/he will not be able to run it anyway.

I thinking of something like "score" based indications:

```
CPU: 230 000   (generic processor score)
GPU: 40 000    (generic GPU score)
+ Network/File I/O read/write requirements
```

That way can I only calculate those scores on the users computer and then compare them, as long as I'm using the same algorithm, but I have no clue about any such algorithm, whose would be sufficient for **real-world software** for desktop usage.

Comment: What kind of software? A game, a number crunching utility, a network intensive product, a I/O-limited application? There are so many different variables and you have given us so little idea as what you're trying to determine.

Comment: All kind of. I know there is many variables, therefore the question, some type of indication maybe is possible, if I receive some information from the software creator

Comment: See my answer below. The answer (can the computer run it or not) depends more on installed libraries/drivers/hardware than on processor/GPU capability. It can be more tricky to write tests for drivers/libraries, but not much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest testing on existence of specific libraries and environment (OS version, video card presence, working sound drivers, DirectX, OpenGL, Gnome, KDE). Assign priorities to these libraries and make comparison using the priorities, e.g. video card presence is more important than KDE presence.

The problem is, even outdated hardware can run most software without issues (just slower), but newest hardware cannot run some software without installing requirements.

For example, I can run Firefox 11 on my Pentium III coppermine (using FreeBSD and X server), but if you install windows XP on the newest hardware with six-core i7 and nVidia GTX 640 it still cannot run DirectX 11 games.

This method requires no assistance from the software creator, but is not 100% accurate.
If you want 90+% accurate information, make the software creator check 5-6 checkboxes before uploading. Example:

- My application requires DirectX/OpenGL/3D acceleration
- My application requires sound
- My application requires Windows Vista or later
- My application requires [high bandwith] network connection

then you can test specific applications using information from these checkboxes.

**Edit**:
I think additional checks could be:

- video/audio codecs
- pixel/vertex/geometry shader version, GPU physics acceleration (may be crucial for games)
- not so much related anymore: processor extensions (SSE2 MMX etc)
- third party software such as pdf, flash, etc
- system libraries (libpng, libjpeg, svg)
- system version (Service Pack number, OS edition (premium professional etc)
- window manager (some apps on OSX require X11 for functioning, some apps on Linux work only on KDE, etc)

These are actual requirements I (and many others) have seen when installing different software.

As for old hardware, if the computer satisfies hardware requirements (pixel shader version, processor extensions, etc), then there's a strong reason to believe the software will run on the system (possibly slower, but that's what benchmarks are for if you need them).

Comment: So in general: priority updated software (libraries) before old hardware, is that correct? Also, can you add more such good questions as you find useful to include, whose are not self explained (the user probably understand it needs a sound device if she/he want to play music) like "DirectX/OpenGL/3D acceleration". Thank you

Comment: No problem. I've added more questions (requirements), see edit.

Answer (score 0):

For GPUs I do not think getting a score is usable/possible without running some code on the machine to test if the machine is up to spec. 
With GPU's this is typically checking what Shader Models it is able to use, and either defaulting to a lower shader model (thus the complexity of the application is of less "quality") or telling them they have no hope of running the code and thus quitting.

Comment: I will run some code to try to make a good suggestion if the computer is capable to run the software or not. Thanks for telling "Shader Models", do you know something else which is often important to check for? thank you

Comment: Memory, speed (#cores etc). Basically it would take a little bit of research on your part first. You would need an idea of how much you application taxes the GPU (throughput: avg calc per pixel etc) then you could compare this to capabilities of the generation of card and then perhaps recommend a setting that the user could pick, or maybe you force one. Depending on what you are actually doing this can be quite an involved process.

Comment: You would perhaps want to generalize this is some meaningful way to you to cut down on ever increasing complexity. Shader model, memory is likely a good start and maybe end point depending on what you are doing.